# Spring Session JDBC - disable session persistence for anonymous requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session

I have a REST API, implemented in Spring Boot, integrated with PostgreSQL and Spring Security. All works seamlessly.

Now I enabled Spring Session JDBC by using `@EnableJdbcHttpSession` and executing the `org.springframework.session.jdbc.schema-postgresql.sql` script. Now my sessions are stored in the DB. Cool.

I soon found that I have a bunch of records in the `spring_session` where the `principal_name` column has `NULL` values. This happens when anonymous user makes calls to the API (ex. try to authenticate but the credentials are wrong).

How can I make Spring to store the sessions only for authenticated/non-anonymous users?

**Side note**: I also got many unwanted `SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST` records in the `spring_session_attributes` table but I was able to disable those by configuring Spring Security:

```
httpSecurity.requestCache().requestCache(new NullRequestCache());
```

Comment: Spring shouldn't create anonymous sessions with `NullRequestCache`. As the documentation states: `Null implementation of RequestCache. Typically used when creation of a session is not desired.` Are you sure that your `configure` method where you call `http.requestCache().requestCache(new NullRequestCache());` is being processed? Can you debug?

Comment: The `NullRequestCache` disables the caching of the requests recorded into the `spring_session_attributes` but the records in `spring_session` are still persisted. I've tested it and it's like that. The documentation is a bit misleading IMO since it actually doesn't tell it won't create a session.

Comment: Well, in my case, it doesn't create sessions. I suspect something else is creating your sessions for anonymous users.

Comment: @HasanCanSaral Thanks, you're right. It is something else. Here is the project I tested with and it seems to work as desired https://github.com/nyxz/persistent-session . I will post an update as soon as I find the actual cause.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? @nyxz

Comment: Hi @MaheshVarma 
This was a while ago but if I can recall I sadly didn't find a workaround for that.