# How to Prevent Session Saving for Anonymous Users or Reduce Its Validity in Spring Session/Spring security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session

I am currently using Spring Boot 3.1 with Spring Session and Spring Security for my project. The main goal is to prevent saving sessions for anonymous users or at least reduce the duration these sessions are valid.

Here is the code for my security filter chain and code with EnableJdbcHttpSession:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> {
                    authorize
                            .requestMatchers(publicPaths)
                            .permitAll()
                            .anyRequest()
                            .authenticated();
                })
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.maximumSessions(3))
                .formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin.loginPage("/login").permitAll())
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());
        return http.build();

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJdbcHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = 10080 * 60)
public class LearningApp {
    //...
}
```

I am currently seeing all sessions being saved in the session_attributes table with the attribute_name SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST, including those for anonymous users. I have tried to limit the maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds with @EnableJdbcHttpSession , but this applies to all sessions.

I need to only save sessions for authenticated users, or reduce the duration for which anonymous sessions are valid (principal_name == null)?

I have tried making a CustomSessionRepository, ref. (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/2302), but I was not able to get sessions for anonymous users with reduced expiry

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52628602/spring-session-jdbc-disable-session-persistence-for-anonymous-requests

I was able to not create session with the help of the above post, adding `.requestCache(requestCache -> requestCache.disable());` to the security configuration. 

But still not sure about reduced validity which can be useful sometimes (I think)